# Angular JavaScript Tree View with drag-and-drop rearrangement of nodes / insertion of nodes

Tags: javascript, angular, treeview

I am a newbie in JavaScript Tree Views and in Angular.
I've searched the web for this topic but was not able to easily find an answer to my question.
I need a tree-view which works well with Angular and can handle larger data sets (tens of thousands of nodes) and which allows me to move nodes around in the tree using drag-and-drop and to insert and delete nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I google it and I find this try this but before implement it get basic of js and angular

[Simple List Demo](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple)

[Nested List demo](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested)

Html

```
    <!-- The dnd-list directive allows to drop elements into it.
     The dropped data will be added to the referenced list -->
<ul dnd-list="list">
    <!-- The dnd-draggable directive makes an element draggable and will
         transfer the object that was assigned to it. If an element was
         dragged away, you have to remove it from the original list
         yourself using the dnd-moved attribute -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in list"
        dnd-draggable="item"
        dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
        ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}"
        >
        {{item.label}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/**
 * The dnd-list should always have a min-height,
 * otherwise you can't drop to it once it's empty
 */
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] {
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

/**
 * The dndDraggingSource class will be applied to
 * the source element of a drag operation. It makes
 * sense to hide it to give the user the feeling
 * that he's actually moving it.
 */
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndDraggingSource {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * An element with .dndPlaceholder class will be
 * added to the dnd-list while the user is dragging
 * over it.
 */
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: block;
    min-height: 42px;
}

.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

/**
 * Show selected elements in green
 */
.simpleDemo ul[dnd-list] li.selected {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    color: #3c763d;
}
```

Angular

```
angular.module("demo").controller("SimpleDemoController", function($scope) {

    $scope.models = {
        selected: null,
        lists: {"A": [], "B": []}
    };

    // Generate initial model
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        $scope.models.lists.A.push({label: "Item A" + i});
        $scope.models.lists.B.push({label: "Item B" + i});
    }

    // Model to JSON for demo purpose
    $scope.$watch('models', function(model) {
        $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
    }, true);

});
```